# ElasticSearch (5.5) query or algorithm required to exctract values against timestamp with an interference pattern

Tags: algorithm, elasticsearch, timestamp, aggregate

I have a very large volume of documents in ElasticSearch (5.5) which hold recorded data at regular time intervals, let's say every 3 seconds.

```
{
   "@timestamp": "2015-10-14T12:45:00Z",
   "channel1": 24.4
},
{
   "@timestamp": "2015-10-14T12:48:00Z",
   "channel1": 25.5
},
{
   "@timestamp": "2015-10-14T12:51:00Z",
   "channel1": 26.6
}
```

Let's say that I need to get results back for a query that asks for the point value every 5 seconds. An interference pattern arises where sometimes there will be an exact match (for simplicity's sake, let's say in the example above that  12:45 is the only sample to land on a multiple of five).

On these times, I want elastic to provide me with the exact value recorded at that time if there is one. So at 12:45 there is a match so it returns value 24.4

In the other cases, I require the last (previously recorded) value. So at 12:50, having no data at that precise time, it would return the value at 12:48 (25.5), being the last known value.

Previously I have used aggregations but in this case this doesnt help because I don't want some average made from a bucket of data, I need either an exact value for an exact time match or a previous value if no match.

I could do this programmatically but performance is a real issue here so I need to come up with the most performant method possible to retrieve the data in the way stated. Returning ALL the elastic data and iterating over the results and checking for a match at each time interval else keeping the item at index i-1 sounds slow and I wonder if it isn't the best way.

Perhaps I am missing a trick with Elastic. Perhaps somebody knows a method to do exactly what I am after?! It would be much appreciated...

The mapping is like so:

```
"mappings": {
  "sampleData": {
    "dynamic": "true",
    "dynamic_templates": [{
      "pv_values_template": {
        "match": "GroupId", "mapping": { "doc_values": true, "store": false, "type": "keyword" }
      }
    }],
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": { "type": "date" },
      "channel1": { "type": "float" },
      "channel2": { "type": "float" },
      "item": { "type": "object" },
      "keys": { "properties": { "count": { "type": "integer" }}},
      "values": { "properties": { "count": { "type": "integer" }}}
    }
  }
}
```

and the (NEST) method being called looks like so:

```
channelAggregation => channelAggregation.DateHistogram("HistogramFilter", histogram => histogram
    .Field(dataRecord => dataRecord["@timestamp"])
    .Interval(interval)
    .MinimumDocumentCount(0)
    .ExtendedBounds(start, end)
    .Aggregations(aggregation => DataFieldAggregation(channelNames, aggregation)));
```

@Nikolay there may be up to around 1400 buckets (maximum of one velue to be returned per pixel available on the chart)

Comment: May I ask you how does your mapping look like? How many buckets do you have (hundreds, thousands)?